# Nsubstitute: Mocking an object Parameter for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I am fairly new to Nsubstitute and unit testing.
I know that in unit testing, you don't care about any other dependencies. So in order for this rule to be applied we mock units.

I have this example to be tested code where a method has an object parameter:

```
class dependency {
  public int A;
  public dependency() {
    // algorithms going on ...
    A = algorithm_output;
  }
}

class toTest {
  public int Xa;
  public void Foo(dependency dep_input){
    Xa = dep_input.A;
    // Xa will be used in an algorithm ...
  }
}
```

I was thinking of mocking the constructor but I could not figure out how in Nsubstitute.
So ultimately, how would I test this?

Comment: You can only mock interfaces and virtual methods with NSubstitute. Constructors are a no-go, as is non-virtual or static methods. Perhaps you should add an interface to your class?

Comment: Likely an interface is what you want to use anyway if you want to test this. If you still have a dependency on an actual class you're likely to still run code in that class that may impact your tests, and you might have to tip-toe around certain behavior in that class to get it to fit properly for your test.

Comment: What if I can't change the code to be tested (for some reason in the project that I am working at) ? @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: If you really can't change the existing code, you can't mock the class `dependency`. If you can change the class `dependency` you can add an interface `Idependency` with `int A;` and change the ctor of `Foo` to `public void Foo(Idependency dep_input)`. Now you can mock or create a stub for `dep_input`

Comment: Code has to be *designed* to be tested. A lot of legacy code cannot be tested simply because it was never designed to allow it. If you cannot change the code, and it isn't virtual "enough" to handle the testing you want to do with it then your code falls into this category. You're going to have to way the risk of not testing it against the cost and risk of changing the code. If you simply absolutely no way never in your dreams can change the code, and it isn't testable in its current form then the answer is this: You can't test it automatically. Increase manual testing to compensate.

Comment: I do agree with you @LasseV.Karlsen . So if I do manage to change the code and added an interface, how would I mock a constructor to set its fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not add a comment because it is too long, so I add an answer:
if you want to test `Foo` you do not need to mock the ctor but `dep_input`. For example if you use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart). But you can also use a stub

```
public interface IDependency
{
    int A { get; }
}

public class Dependency : IDependency
{
    public int A { get; private set; }

    public Dependency()
    {
        // algorithms going on ...
        A = algorithm_output();
    }

    private static int algorithm_output()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

public class ToTest
{
    public int Xa;

    public void Foo(IDependency dep_input)
    {
        Xa = dep_input.A;
        // Xa will be used in an algorithm ...
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TestWithMoq()
    {
        var dependecyMock = new Mock<IDependency>();
        dependecyMock.Setup(d => d.A).Returns(23);

        var toTest = new ToTest();
        toTest.Foo(dependecyMock.Object);

        Assert.AreEqual(23, toTest.Xa);
        dependecyMock.Verify(d => d.A, Times.Once);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestWithStub()
    {
        var dependecyStub = new DependencyTest();

        var toTest = new ToTest();
        toTest.Foo(dependecyStub);

        Assert.AreEqual(23, toTest.Xa);
    }

    internal class DependencyTest : IDependency
    {
        public int A
        {
            get
            {
                return 23;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! This is a very helpful example. Thanks! @Dominik